# MKRouteStep extectedTravelTime

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, navigation, mapkit

I am trying to determine if there is a way to tell how long each step in MKRoute takes (travel time). I know MKRoute gives `step` with which we can find the distance of the step, but the travel time of the step is not given. Is there a simpler to find the time than calling the directions request again on that step to find the time?

**Edit:** What I am trying to accomplish on the whole is to point out the coordinates at a certain time or distance for the given route. I just need an efficient way to figure out the time problem.

Comment: If an approximation is good enough (assuming all steps can be covered at the same speed, etc), you could get the ratio of the step distance relative to the total route distance and multiply the total route time by that ratio to get an approximate step time.

Comment: Cannot really assume that steps would be the same speed because there could state highways and interstates in the route, along with city roads.

Comment: Then I think you'll have to get directions for each step.